# Eclipse git commits in other branch disappeared

Tags: java, eclipse, git, git-branch

I coded some features in a separate branch of my project, and today I wanted to commit and push them to my repository.
I made some commits, and after that, I tried to push them, and Eclipse told me, there were no things to push. I was very irritated, because everything worked every time in the master branch. And now, that I first time wanted to do this in an other branch, it does not work.
After that I switched to the master branch, there was also nothing to commit and to push, so I wanted to switch back to my dev branch and there the complete code, coded in this branch, disappeared, it looked like the master branch.

My question is now, how to get back my code and optionally how to push it in my branch.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflog view to find your missing work. Than you can restore your branch by switching to it and resetting its head with the commit from reflog.